# jquery parseFloat, parseInt

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation, I'm using jquery and I need to sum up some fields on my form. 
I have found the NaN error in my **subtotal field** and **total field.**
I have tried everything possible to avoid this type of error, I just need the SUM on this field.
Everything in my form is working fine, only this 2 fields with a problem.
I'm using `parseFloat()` and no response. Only a field with **NaN**

Follow my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        $('#valor, #taxa, #imposto, #envio, #taxa_adicional, #subtotal, #total').blur(function(){

                    // exemplo antigo var val = $('#valor').val();
                    var val = $('#valor').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
                var tax = $('#taxa').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
                var imp = $('#imposto').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
                var env = $('#envio').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
                var xat = $('#taxa_adicional').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 

                if(val == "") val = 0;
                if(tax == "") tax = 0;
                if(imp == "") imp = 0;
                if(env == "") env = 0;
                if(xat == "") xat = 0;

                    var subtotal = parseFloat("val") + parseFloat("tax") + parseFloat("imp") + parseFloat("env");
                var total = parseFloat(val) + parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(imp) + parseFloat(env) + parseFloat(xat);

                    $('#subtotal').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
                $('#total').val(total);
        })

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter! :-/

**WARNING:** I'm using a plugin called:
*jquery.numberformatter - Formatting/Parsing Numbers in jQuery Written by Michael Abernethy*

Comment: @Fernando This is a great example of redundant code which can be optimized by defining a function.

Comment: @SimeVidas I, for one, would love to see your optimized version of this code. Obviously it won't be too much for you to do, since you can see it so clearly.

Comment: @Fernando When posting questions with code that uses plug-ins, it is a good idea to include the information about the plug-in(s). format() is part of which plug-in?

Comment: Yeah! I'm new to jquery and I know nothing about it. I just want to solve the problem of parseInt or parseFloat .. do you know how can I show the sumed value using that method? I apreciate your answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @drachenstern I will be delighted to do it. However, first I need the information about the plug-in that the OP is using, since I need to know what exactly the format method does.

Comment: @SimeVidas ~ Yeah, I was just looking for that myself on the big ole goog and about to come back here to ask him what plugin he was using ;)

Comment: @Fernando, it wasn't really a tip, but a question. `what plugin are you using for format`?

Comment: I believe it's this one: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter

Comment: I'm using  jquery.numberformatter - Formatting/Parsing Numbers in jQuery Written by Michael Abernethy. I can post here the whole plugin, since I can't found the url where I downloaded it before!

Comment: Yeah. The plugin is that one on this address: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter

Comment: @drachenstern Optimized version is here: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/numberformatter-demo.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="box">    
    <p> Valor: <input id="valor"> </p>
    <p> Taxa: <input id="taxa"> </p>
    <p> Imposto: <input id="imposto"> </p>
    <p> Envio: <input id="envio"> </p>
    <p> Taxa adicional: <input id="taxa_adicional"> </p>   
    <p> Subtotal: <span id="subtotal">0</span> </p>
    <p> Total: <span id="total">0</span> </p>   
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var options = {
        format: '#,###.00',
        locale: 'br'
    },
    inputs = $( 'input:text', '#box' ).get(),
    input_adicional = $( '#taxa_adicional' )[0],
    input_total = $( '#total' )[0],
    input_subtotal = $( '#subtotal' )[0];
```

and then:

```
$( inputs ).add( [ input_total, input_subtotal ] ).format( options );

$( inputs ).
    blur( function () {
        var total = 0,
            subtotal = 0;

        // on blur, format the field
        $( this ).format( options );

        // calculate the sum of all input fields
        $( inputs ).each( function () {
            total += +$( this ).parse( options );
        });

        // subtotal doesn't include the "additional" field  
        subtotal = total - $( input_adicional ).parse( options );

        // populate the SPAN's with the sums and format the nubmers
        $( input_subtotal ).text( subtotal ).format( options );
        $( input_total ).text( total ).format( options );
    }).
    focus( function () {
        // if the field contains the value 0, empty it
        if ( +$( this ).parse( options ) === 0 ) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/U9V6x/

Comment: Thanks @Sime.
I change the line: format: "#.###,00", locale: "br" to: format: "#,###.00", locale: "us"
AND it work perfectly! Thanks again man.
I'm new to jquery sorry!.

Comment: And How I get the values from a span tag to send it via form ? since span tag is not a form field. I'm really staked mixing php and jquery.. was not a good idea. :-(

Comment: I found a solution, something a little dirt but work fine.. 
First I get the total into a var 
Second I use location.href="myPage.php?total=" + total;
to reload my page itself and now I get the total via php method $_GET[total]. 
The job is done! pretty dirt, but solve the problem!! Thanks every one that help a lot.

Comment: @Fernando Yea, that would be one solution. However, consider using Ajax. jQuery has easy-to-use Ajax methods that allow you to send stuff to the server-side. With Ajax, you wouldn't have to reload the entire page, which would increase the user experience.

Comment: @Sime I need agree with you, but jquery for me is something extreme hard to learn, since I have no experence on this kind of client-side language, I'm used to write code only in server-side language like PHP and java...  Anyway I appreciate your help. I will try to learn a little of jquery day-by-day.

Comment: @Fernando It's actually quite easy once you get the basic concepts. For example, an Ajax alternative for your above issue could be: `$.post("myPage.php", { total: total } );` The jQuery documentation has examples and there also are tutorials out there. Or you could just ask another question on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I see, but since I have $.post("myPage.php", { total: total } ); How Do I retrieve the total in my php variable?   echo $_GET['someValue'];
  I try to use $_GET but it is not the way. I'm almost giving up ..

Comment: @Fernando I don't know PHP, but isn't there a $_POST object? Alternatively, you could just use the jQuery get() function instead: `$.get("myPage.php", { total: total } );`

Comment: @Sime yeah in PHP has $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST objects. But wheb I call the javascript with $_GET it returns nothing. But when I do like this »» var someValue = $(".total").text(); alert("O Total é "+someValue); It show an alert to me. I just need to catch the value in my alert box. Once I have the value I can do whatever I want. But I have no Idea how to do this.

Comment: @Fernando What do you mean by - *"when I call the JavaScript with $_GET it returns nothing"*? $_GET is on the server-side, and JavaScript is on the client-side.

Comment: @Sime I'm trying to put a value from client-side inside a var on the server-side. But I think it is impossible. 
How can I solve this problem? I need to send the total in my form to put it value insisde my database. Any Idea? thanks

Comment: @Fernando If you use `$.get("myPage.php", { foo: "hello" } );` on the client-side, then `$_GET["foo"]` should work on the server-side and return the "hello" string. Try it out... If it doesn't work, you're best of asking another question, since I don't know PHP and therefore cannot help you out here.

Comment: Dead link means optimization is for naught.

Comment: @Dave I've included the HTML and JavaScript code, plus I made a demo on jsFiddle. Thanks for letting me know about the dead link.

Answer (score 5):

When you're calculating your subtotal, you are calling parseFloat() on a series of strings, not the variables themselves. The line should be:

```
 var subtotal = parseFloat(val) + parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(imp) + parseFloat(env);
```

Comment: not work at all, still to return 0.00 ... Do you Have Idea what can it be?

Comment: @Fernando Don't use parseFloat! The plug-in has a dedicated method for parsing the formatted value. Check out my working demo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

That plugin will take an element, parse the value according to the format, and reinsert it into the DOM, from what I can tell. So I'm going to assume that's the case.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#valor, #taxa, #imposto, #envio, #taxa_adicional, #subtotal, #total').blur(function(){
/*
  // first update all fields to have the correct format, so we can work with them later.
  $('#valor').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
  $('#taxa').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
  $('#imposto').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
  $('#envio').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
  $('#taxa_adicional').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
*/
  //separating because I'm pretty sure this would work in place of all those lines of code:
  // needs testing though. If this doesn't work uncomment the previous block and delete this line
  $('#valor,#taxa,#imposto,#envio,#taxa_adicional').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 

  // then since the values have been formatted, let's extract just the floats like you wanted
  // going through the document.getElementById since the jQuery wrapper is useless overhead and you don't need a jQuery object back out.
  var val = parseFloat( document.getElementById('val').innerHTML );
  var tax = parseFloat( document.getElementById('taxa').innerHTML );
  var imp = parseFloat( document.getElementById('imposto').innerHTML );
  var env = parseFloat( document.getElementById('envio').innerHTML );
  var xat = parseFloat( document.getElementById('taxa_adicional').innerHTML );

  if( isNaN( val ) ) val = 0;
  if( isNaN( tax ) ) tax = 0;
  if( isNaN( imp ) ) imp = 0;
  if( isNaN( env ) ) env = 0;
  if( isNaN( xat ) ) xat = 0;

  var subtotal = val + tax + imp + env;
  var total = val + tax + imp + env + xat;

  $('#subtotal').val(subtotal).format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
  $('#total').val(total).format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
 });
});
```

Notice that I am only trying to help you have easier to read code. There are probably lots of ways to write this to get it *leaner[1]*

[1] less fat; less waste; ~ Perhaps this translates, perhaps it is an idiom?

Comment: I swaped the line var subtotal = val + tax + imp + env; with the line var subtotal = parseFloat(val) + parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(imp) + parseFloat(env); and it still to return 0.00 It's a good start, before only NaN .. thanks still looking for a solution..

Comment: @FernandoCosta ~ To be clear, you can't cut and paste only bits of my code, yeah? I just want to be clear that's not what you were doing, because that wouldn't have worked regardless. Also, I'm not entirely sure my code does what you want, like someone else noted, you should've used the provided numeric parser in that library instead of my parsing method.

Comment: I appreciate your preoccupation, thanks for any help. Your code give me new ideas about what I need to do, I 'm not copying and pasting code, I'm developing something with jquery and I have never used this technology before, but I have learned a lot with persons like you. Really Thanks. Now back to the code. :-/

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

$(document).ready( function() {

```
    $('#valor, #taxa, #imposto, #envio, #taxa_adicional, #subtotal, #total').blur(function(){

                // exemplo antigo var val = $('#valor').val();
                var val = $('#valor').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
            var tax = $('#taxa').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
            var imp = $('#imposto').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 
            var env = $('#envio').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
            var xat = $('#taxa_adicional').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"}); 

            if(isNan(parseFloat(val))) val = 0;
            if(isNan(parseFloat(tax))) tax = 0;
            if(isNan(parseFloat(imp))) imp = 0;
            if(isNan(parseFloat(env))) env = 0;
            if(isNan(parseFloat(xat))) xat = 0;

                var subtotal = parseFloat("val") + parseFloat("tax") + parseFloat("imp") + parseFloat("env");
            var total = parseFloat(val) + parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(imp) + parseFloat(env) + parseFloat(xat);

                $('#subtotal').format({format:"#,###.00", locale:"br"});
            $('#total').val(total);
    })
```

});

Comment: Hrm. the problem here is that parseFloat("3,400.00") == 3.  This is because parseFloat looks at the first numeric chars until it reaches a non-numeric char.  you will want to strip the "#,###.00" of its comma.  Worse yet, I think there may be a currency symbol in your string?

Comment: What is the string value of the variable val before it is parsed?